# mpi4py Send() complaining about wrong number of arguments

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

System information:

OS: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (yes, it's very old)

Machine: Mac Pro, mid 2010

Processor: 2 x 2.66 GHz 6-Core Intel Xeon

Storage: 814 GB free of 1000 GB total

Memory: 24 GB RAM

I am attempting to use the mpi4py package to parallelize a set of simulations, but my installation appears to be faulty.  To test the package, I copy/pasted a script from mpi4py's  documentation site into its own file and ran it as instructed in the documentation:

```
mpiexec -n 4 python trapParallel_1.py 0.0 1.0 10000
```

(the script and and docs are here: http://materials.jeremybejarano.com/MPIwithPython/pointToPoint.html#parallelizing-the-trapezoidal-rule; the script I copied is trapParallel_1.py).

However, when I run the script, I get the following error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trapParallel_1.py", line 59, in <module>
    comm.Send(integral)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 264, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Send (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:92839)
TypeError: Send() takes at least 2 positional arguments (1 given)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trapParallel_1.py", line 59, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trapParallel_1.py", line 59, in <module>
    comm.Send(integral)
    comm.Send(integral)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 264, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Send (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:92839)
  File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 264, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Send (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:92839)
TypeError: Send() takes at least 2 positional arguments (1 given)
TypeError: Send() takes at least 2 positional arguments (1 given)
```

I made no edits to the code-- I took it directly from the documentation.  I have also checked the mpi4py api reference, which states that Send() takes one positional argument.  Assuming the code is correct, I believe the problem is with my installation of mpi4py or mpi, but can't figure out what the problem is.  I installed mpi4py with pip:

```
pip install mpi4py
```

To install mpi, I first installed mpich version 3.2 from here: https://www.mpich.org/downloads/.  I downloaded a tarball to my downloads folder, expanded it, and built mpich from source, running:

```
cd ~/Downloads/mpich-3.2
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local/mpich2
make
make install
```

When I first obtained the error, my next step was to try and install OpenMPI, for which I used Homebrew:

```
brew install open-mpi
```

This did not resolve the problem.  I tried rebuilding mpich to no effect; then, when that didn't work, I ran `make uninstall` from mpich's source directory and manually removed every file or directory I could find that included 'mpich' in the name.  The script still generated the same error.

Ordinarily I would suspect that the mpi4py installation is the problem.  However, I know that mpi4py uses Cython, and I'm not sure how Cython works (ie, the Send() method may be a wrapper for something not in mpi itself, in which case the mpi installation could be the problem).

In addition, before I uninstalled mpich, I ran `make testing` from the mpich source directory and looked at the file `summary.xml`, which summarizes the test results.  According to the file, everything passed except one test.  The error message is below:

```
<NAME>gather_big</NAME>
<NP>8</NP>
<WORKDIR>./coll</WORKDIR>
<STATUS>fail</STATUS>
<TESTDIFF>
[mpiexec@ilims-mac-pro] APPLICATION TIMED OUT
[proxy:0:0@ilims-mac-pro] HYD_pmcd_pmip_control_cmd_cb (pm/pmiserv/pmip_cb.c:885): assert (!closed) failed
[proxy:0:0@ilims-mac-pro] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (tools/demux/demux_poll.c:76): callback returned error status
[proxy:0:0@ilims-mac-pro] main (pm/pmiserv/pmip.c:206): demux engine error waiting for event
[mpiexec@ilims-mac-pro] HYDT_bscu_wait_for_completion (tools/bootstrap/utils/bscu_wait.c:76): one of the processes terminated badly; aborting
[mpiexec@ilims-mac-pro] HYDT_bsci_wait_for_completion (tools/bootstrap/src/bsci_wait.c:23): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@ilims-mac-pro] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:189): launcher returned error waiting for completion
[mpiexec@ilims-mac-pro] main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:344): process manager error waiting for completion
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I change line 59 from `comm.Send(integral)` to `comm.Send(integral, numpy.zeros(1))`, I get the right answer.

Comment: I'd still like to know why the example code won't work though

Comment: Please limit the question to a single topic, e.g. the tutorial code doesn't work. Ask about the installation problems in separate questions. Relying on a 5 year old tutorial is rarely a good idea. The mpi4py documentation is unfortunately horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this example was written for a previous version of `mpi4py` (i did notifiy the author about this)

the `dest` parameter used to be optional (send to rank 0 by default) but is now mandatory

> commit e6765257b2d4e4d37dd5471b2ab07014ab4d9b02 Author: Lisandro
>   Dalcin  Date:   Sat May 10 14:17:16 2014 +0300
>
> Change signature of all send methods,
>
> - 'dest' is a required argument.

the right fix here is to replace

```
comm.Send(integral)
```

with

```
comm.Send(integral, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you!  Also I appreciate you notifying the author.